# AngularJS - Dynamically add and remove form fields within a table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I wanna add a couple of form fields, dynamically on a button press and all that fields to be in a table (every field to have his own space something like this: `<td>field</td>`

This is what I have until now and if I put all the code in the table it doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
      <select>
         <option>option 1</option>
         <option>option 2</option>
         <option>option 3</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter data">
       <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter data 2">
      <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
   </fieldset>
   <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>
       
   <div id="choicesDisplay">
      {{ choices }}
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}, {id: 'choice2'}];
  
  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
  };
    
  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
  };
  
});
```

Here is a link to JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rnnb32rm/1014/

Comment: What is it that is not working? I am able to add fields to table

Comment: @SandeepNayak i wanna every field to by in a table something like this: <tr><td> <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter data"></td>
<td> <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter data"></td>
<td> <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter data"></td>

Comment: Try to change markup -- see https://jsfiddle.net/ykvo0hy6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added table data to your example and i think it works fine?

The only thing you really have to do is replace your `fieldset` with a `tr` node and then wrap your inputs in `td` nodes - and wrap the whole thing in a `table` node ofcourse.

https://jsfiddle.net/9tk0qpng/1/